# Python - How can I calculate the integrale in a contour?

Tags: python, numpy, integration, contour

I am trying to determine the contour integral with Python.
Does anyone have experience for this? I m try to calculate that on the contour "Gamma" (a figure is located below):

[image]

My data are here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot

#definition of position point
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 10)
r = 1
x1= r*np.cos(theta)
x2 = r*np.sin(theta)

plt.plot(x1, x2, 'k-',linewidth=5)

#quantities A and B
A = np.array([ 0.24872107,  0.3806164 ,  0.30198209,  0.14252744,  0.02832797,
        0.04871077,  0.03160013,  0.13847697,  0.29831411,  0.32951613])

B = np.array([ 0.26101962,  0.56653762,  0.00908769, -0.05911249,  0.03449575,
        0.04463307,  0.0333772 ,  0.34940976,  0.54600592,  0.14270376])
```

The equation is above and a figure shows the problem.

[image]

Comment: Have you attempted to write it yourself yet?

Comment: I have some difficulties to write it just some help to launch me ;)

Comment: I m not very good in integral calculation

Comment: Please explain those difficulties, it's much more useful to us than just a "how do you do this".

Comment: I dont know how to begin to deal with so it is difficult to explain. In my other questions i do this but here i cant sorry

Comment: But i think there is an interest for the communauty

Comment: Then maybe it's too early to ask us this question :) Do some more research on the topic, then come back when you hit an obstacle in the implementation.

Comment: Why are your `A` and `B` in the equation 2d, when your arrays are 1d? How does `B(x1,x2)` correspond with `B[i]`?